# Openstack Instance syslog

Tags: openstack, syslog, rsyslog, openstack-nova

I need to get the syslog of the instances created by openstack. I am able to get console log but I need the syslog of the instance. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

the usual location to find syslogs is `/var/log/syslog`.
if you don't find it, you can configure each component to log to a different syslog facility.

nova.conf:

```
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0
```

glance-api.conf and glance-registry.conf:

```
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL1
```

cinder.conf:

```
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL2
```

keystone.conf:

```
use_syslog=True
syslog_log_facility=LOG_LOCAL3
```

By default, Object Storage logs to syslog.